# UDP server doesn't send audio properly back

Tags: java, networking, audio, udp

So i'm having some issues fingering out how to properly receive audio back from the server. Currently the client records audio then sends it over to server. In the server is arrives fine however when i'm sending it back to they client i hear some static sound everytime i speak something into the microphone instead of the actual noice/voice.

Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException {
    new server();
}

public server() {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
    t1.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
    SourceDataLine speakers = null;


    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
    try {
        speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        speakers.open(format);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    speakers.start();


    try {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(5555);
        
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket receive = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        
        while (true) {
            serverSocket.receive(receive);

            //out.write(receive.getData(), 0, receive.getData().length);
            //speakers.write(receive.getData(), 0, receive.getData().length);
            
            InetAddress ip = receive.getAddress();
            int clientPort = receive.getPort();
            
                DatagramPacket send = new DatagramPacket(receive.getData(), receive.getData().length, ip, clientPort);
                serverSocket.send(send);
            
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Timeout error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    
}
```

Client:

```
public class client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new client();
}

public client() throws Exception {
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);

    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        System.out.println("received");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    DataLine.Info dli = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
                    SourceDataLine speakers = null;
                    try {
                        speakers = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dli);
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    try {
                        speakers.open();
                        speakers.start();
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    speakers.write(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getData().length);//here the client should hear the response back
                                                                                 //but it doesn't work
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        TargetDataLine microphone = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        microphone.open(format);

        // for report
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] data = new byte[microphone.getBufferSize() / 5];
        microphone.start();

        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            int numBytesRead;

            for (;;) {
                numBytesRead = microphone.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE);
                // bytesRead += numBytesRead;
                // write the mic data to a stream for use later
                out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);

                DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(data, numBytesRead, address, 5555);
                socket.send(request);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you creating a new SourceDataLine for every packet received?

Comment: Is that wrong? The answer is yes.

Comment: Glad that helped! Could you write down the answer and mark it solved? (I can do this if you prefer.) Main thing is to not waste the time of the good people who are looking for questions to help solve, and to make the solution easier to spot for those who have similar problem and come across this thread via search.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Client` code, you are creating a new `SourceDataLine` *speakers* upon receipt of each datagram. The instantiation should be outside of the `while` loop, similar to your handling of the `TargetDataLine`.